# regexing a string that sometimes has a space and sometimes not

Tags: regex, scala, gatling

This is my response

```
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('idForm').submit()">
<form id="idForm" action="https://x.y-test.z:443/hpp-webapp/hentpasient.html?ticket=I6VZgglkX/Z2z1GJYY1TzIqAscCJbWPI5pPBLl38VCEHcD/qh9qSz MzAIVv 6H2fau4DFMQscbPqy1HhFkgvg==" method="POST"
      target="_top">
```

and I want to regex (scala/gatling) the value of `<ticket>`.

Tried this:

```
.check(regex("<form id=\"idForm\" action=\"https://x.y-test.z:443/hpp-webapp/hentpasient.html?ticket=\"(.*?)\"").saveAs("jwtUncoded"))
```

But I get

```
> regex(<form id="idForm" action="https://x.y-z      1 (100,0%)
.no:443/hpp-webapp/hentpasient.html?ticket="(.*?)").find.exist...
```

When observing the output in Gatling I can see that the value of `<ticket>` sometimes has a space and sometimes not.

How can I regex this value?

Answer (score 1):

```
regex("ticket=(.*?)\"")
```

Your own take has a wrong quote before the capture group.

Comment: @jwvh no idea what you mean. The `?` is here to make the pattern reluctant instead of greedy, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: Oops. My bad. I would have used `[^"]*`. Please disregard.

Comment: got error using this:   .check(regex("\"ticket=(.*?)\\\"\")").saveAs("jwtUncoded"))
---- Errors --------------------------------------------------------------------
> j.u.r.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' near index      1 (100,0%)
 15  "ticket=(.*?)\"")

Comment: is there a way in Gatling to say that the value extracted here (ticket) should not be HTML Decoded? (I am porting some Visual Studio tests to Gatling and the value extracted here has this property in Visual Studio.

Comment: @jwvh Makes sense too.

Answer (score -1):

```
.check(regex("ticket=(.*?)\"").saveAs("jwtUncoded"))
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what @StephaneLANDELLE suggested 9 hours ago?

Comment: Yes it is. @Magnus Jensen Please validate my answer.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25734915)